# Why does <h4> height change when I change a heading to display: inline?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
<h4>Hello</h4>
<h4 class="a">Hello</h4>
<h4 class="b">Hello</h4>

h4 {  
    font: normal 12px/23px Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0 7px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC; background-color: red;
}
h4.a { display: inline; }
h4.b { display: inline; height: 23px; }
```

Example: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LYBKP/)

What I need is for the height of the heading to remain the same but for the width to not be full width. I changed to inline but I notice that now the height changes. Can someone explain how I can keep it the same height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You quite simply can't apply an explicit `height` value to an element with `display: inline`.

What if you made it `display: inline-block` instead?

Comment: works good and I'll use that. I guess there are some browser issues but time for my users to upgrade anyway :-)

Comment: @SamanthaJ - The browser issues with inline block are... IE6 and IE7: Easy work around using the star hack and inline `*display:inline;` and Firefox2: No good work-around, but really how many people are using FF2 now?

Comment: @Spudley: `display: -moz-inline-box`, but yeah who uses it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to use `float: left`